# select the next button- xpath-selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, cucumber, cucumber-serenity

I am exactly in the line where there is the text ='Ver Informe'.

I want to go to the button that is next to that line.

Because only work when I make the click there.

Could you help me go there?

I tried: /button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMDo7.png) -- and doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I need to see more of the surrounding html but if I understand your question correctly you want the button that contains the element with the text 'Ver informe'.
Try this:

```
//div[4]//article[1]//descendant::button[@type='button' and ./*[contains(text(),'Ver informe')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

basically the span is wrapped in the button tag. So you can use the below xpath.

```
//span[normalize-space(.)='Ver informe']/parent::button
```